# Glib AppInfo.create_from_commandline with NEEDS_TERMINAL only launches xterm or gnome-terminal

Tags: glib, vala

Why is this code only launching xterm or gnome terminal ?
I don't understand why it is not using user default terminal (x-terminal-emulator) on Debian, or even KDE default terminal.

```
AppInfo ai = AppInfo.create_from_commandline (
  "ssh %s".printf (this.title),
  "ssh", AppInfoCreateFlags.NEEDS_TERMINAL);
ai.launch (null, null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of what GDesktopAppInfo tries: [gio/gdesktopappinfo.c#L2467-L2494](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/cd1eba043c90da3aee8f5cd51b205b2e2c16f08e/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c#L2467-L2494)

I believe the problem is that *x-terminal-emulator* is not standardized. If one were to push that as a freedesktop standard it would likely get implemented.